# Can I do anything in A Dark Room?

Tags: candy-box-2

In the castle there's a room that is dark. I can't seem to do anything in there, is it solely there as a reference to another game or is there something to be done here?

Comment: Interesting note, with colors inverted the room is all white until the fire is lit.

Comment: The point to that room is to grope around in the dark like with a real-life dark room. –‿◉

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can click at the center of the room. It'll light up a campfire and you'll be able to get a pitchfork to triple your lollipop income

Answer (score 6):

This is actually a reference to a great game called [a-dark-room](/questions/tagged/a-dark-room). And it's not actually directly to the center, it is a little left and down. Just try mousing over the center-ish area until you get a mouse hand.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten that far, but have you tried wearing the Red enchanted gloves? Description says they emit a red light when it's dark.

Comment: They don't do anything.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that seems to be a red herring (and it took me forever to figure out where I had seen something mention emitting a light in the dark).

Answer (score 0):

> I can't get what i done, probably just clicking around that room, then fire appeared. There was a pitchfork for 3x boosting lollipop production

Answer (score 0):

You must click in the center and a campfire will appear with a pitchfork.